# setar campo enum como null na procedure

Tags: sql-update, mysql

Eu tenho uma procedure que recebo alguns dados e estes podem vir vazios até ai tudo bem, mas quando o campo é enum e tento setar como null dá erro de Data truncated for column mesmo o campo podendo receber nulo.

Exemplo:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fichacadastral_u`(
p_id_efetivo int(11) ,
p_origem_cert_reservista enum('Aeronáutica','Exército','Marinha')
)
BEGIN


        update _rh.efetivo
            set 
            origem_cert_reservista = if(p_origem_cert_reservista <> '', p_origem_cert_reservista, null)
            where id_efetivo = p_id_efetivo;
            
    
        select 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso.' as msg, 0 as erro;

END
```

se eu fizer uma simples query tipo

```
update _rh.efetivo set origem_cert_reservista = null where id_efetivo = 4;
```

vai de boa.

poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de como usar e o código que eu desenvolvi aqui.

```
-- Criando a procedure
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insere_enum_null`(
  IN `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, 
  IN `situacao_nova` ENUM('Cancelado','Ativo','Inativo','Teste')
)
COMMENT 'fazendo o teste passando null para o enum da procedure'
BEGIN

update situacoes 
set situacao = if(situacao_nova <> '', situacao_nova, null)
where id_situacao = id;
            
select 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso.' as msg, 0 as erro;

END$$
delimiter ;

-- Tabela de situações 

CREATE table if not exists `situacoes` (
  `id_situacao` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `situacao` enum('Cancelado','Ativo','Inativo','Teste') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'contém as situações possíveis'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Tabela usada para teste de procedure insere_enum_null';

-- Inserindo dados na tabela `situacoes`

INSERT INTO `situacoes` (`id_situacao`, `situacao`) VALUES
(1, 'Ativo'),
(2, NULL);
```

Agora chamando os dados para comparações

```
select * from situacoes;

call insere_enum_null(1,'Cancelado');

select * from situacoes;

call insere_enum_null(1, null);

select * from situacoes;
```

Se quiser pode visualizar online aqui:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8S5ENuugifFRUKWf6Z9iP/0

Comment: agradeço a sua ajuda mas desse jeito quando vem vazio ou zero dá erro de data truncate encontrei uma solução e vou colocar a resposta aqui

Comment: Entendi então é bem mais simples, só fazer a verificação usando if, ifnull etc.

Answer (score 0):

encontrei a solução, coloquei o campo que vou receber o enum como int e envio 0 no caso de vazio ai seto como null

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fichacadastral_u`(
p_id_efetivo int(11) ,
p_origem_cert_reservista int(1)
)
BEGIN


        update _rh.efetivo
            set 
            origem_cert_reservista = if(p_origem_cert_reservista > 0, p_origem_cert_reservista, null)
            where id_efetivo = p_id_efetivo;
            
    
        select 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso.' as msg, 0 as erro;

END
```